# Set proxy autoconfigure in chrome

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android

To access some of my work web pages from my desktop firefox I use proxy autoconfigure . I just enter http://wwwcache.xxx.xx.xxx/autoconfig into the settings. How can I do the same thing in chrome in android?